# Where can I find the divider sheet template for Panasonic kv-s3065c scanner

Tags: scanner

The Panasonic kv-s3065c scanner can recognize separation sheets to split the documents. The manual states that the PDF can be found on the CD... but the software is distributed on-line and I can't find the PDF in any of the installed program files.

Anyone has an idea where I can find this PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a place where I could download them:

http://itcimaging.com/v7/downloads/scanners/panasonic/110-control-sheets